# Removing many to many reference in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many, nosql

One of my mongoose schemas is a many to many relationship:

```js
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   name       : String,
   groups  : [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Group'} ]
});

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
   name       : String,
   users  : [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'} ]
});
```

If I remove a group, is there anyway to remove that group objectId from all the user's 'groups' array?

```js
GroupSchema.pre('remove', function(next){
    //Remove group._id from all the users
})
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're on the right track to use `'remove'` middleware for this.  In the middleware function, `this` is the group instance being removed and you can access the other models via its `model` method.  So you can do something like:

```
GroupSchema.pre('remove', function(next){
    this.model('User').update(
        {_id: {$in: this.users}}, 
        {$pull: {groups: this._id}}, 
        {multi: true},
        next
    );
});
```

Or if you want to support cases where the `users` field in your group instance may not be complete you could do:

```
GroupSchema.pre('remove', function(next){
    this.model('User').update(
        {groups: this._id}, 
        {$pull: {groups: this._id}}, 
        {multi: true},
        next
    );
});
```

But as WiredPrairie notes, for this option you'd want an index on `groups` for good performance.

Comment: And if `groups` isn't indexed, you'll force a full table scan and array scan of users.

Comment: @WiredPrairie There's a way around that if the doubly-linked references are reliable.  I added that as a better option.

Comment: Looks genuine, but how could this.model('user') work since this referes to group schema, this.model is not a function

Comment: @SuhaybKharabsheh `this` refers to the group Model instance (the document being deleted), which does have a [`model` method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-model).

Answer (score 0):

I use my patched version of mongoose-relationship "plugin" to solve this: take a look on 
https://github.com/begrossi/mongoose-relationship/tree/remove-from-parent-if-removed-from-child-set.

Bruno Grossi